# Is there a design pattern for chained observers?

Tags: design-patterns, observer-pattern

Several times, I've found myself in a situation where I want to add functionality to an existing `Observer`-`Observable` relationship.

For example, let's say I have an `Observable` class called `PriceFeed`, instances of which are created by a variety of `PriceSources`.  `Observers` on this are notified whenever the underlying `PriceSource` updates the `PriceFeed` with a new price.

Now I want to add a feature that allows a (temporary) override to be set on the `PriceFeed`.  The `PriceSource` should still update prices on the `PriceFeed`, but for as long as the override is set, whenever a consumer asks `PriceFeed` for it's current value, it should get the override.

The way I did this was to introduce a new `OverrideablePriceFeed` that is itself both an `Observer` and an `Observable`, and that decorates the actual `PriceFeed`.  It's implementation of `.getPrice()` is straight from Chain of Responsibility, but how about the handling of Observable events?  When an override is set or cleared, it should issue it's own event to `Observers`, as well as forwarding events from the underlying `PriceFeed`.

I think of this as some kind of a chained observer, and was curious if there's a more definitive description of a similar pattern.

Comment: [Chain-of-responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) "pattern consisting of a source of command objects and a series of processing objects. Each processing object contains logic that defines the types of command objects that it can handle; the rest are passed to the next processing object in the chain. A mechanism also exists for adding new processing objects to the end of this chain.In a variation of the standard chain-of-responsibility model, some handlers may act as dispatchers, capable of sending commands out in a variety of directions..."

Comment: Yeah, I know CoR.  It does a good job of describing the 'getPrice' handling, but I don't think of it as handling the event forwarding piece of the puzzle.  I'll update my question.

Comment: "...In a variation of the standard chain-of-responsibility model, some handlers may act as **[dispatchers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch)**, capable of sending commands out in a variety of directions, forming a _tree of responsibility_..."

Comment: Decorating observers is just decorating observers. Many of the patterns combine to yield more powerful constructs.

Comment: @gnat yeah, but I read that as simply a CoR implementation that, instead of having a single next link to delegate to, has N.  No?

Comment: @Telastyn Good point, but in this case I think there's questions as to how to handle some details which aren't obvious (at least to me).  eg: when should the decorator remove itself as an observer on the decorated PriceFeed?  If there was a pattern for this combination, then perhaps it would include best practices for answering that kind of question.

Comment: @sharakan - why? A decorator should never remove itself from what it decorates. This isn't specific to your particular usage.

Comment: @Telastyn I'm thinking garbage collection.  In this case there's a circular reference, in a 'normal' decoration it's unidirectional.  If you don't break the Observer reference between the WrappedPriceFeed and the PriceFeed, then WrappedPriceFeed can't be GCed if it's life span << that of the PriceFeed.  The alternative of course is using a soft reference of some kind

Comment: @sharakan if your decoratee knows about your decorator, you have worse problems than a dangling reference.

Comment: @Telastyn And yet, given that the decorator is receiving events from the decoratee, how could the decoratee NOT know about the decorator?  This is kind of my point about the answers to some of these questions not being obvious.

Answer (score 1):

That's called *Reactive Programming.*

Look at Rx.

Rx is all about this.

It treats observables as enumerables and then what you are doing becomes as simple as calling map on the first sequence of events.

```
 events.map(new function(each) { return override != null ? override : each }
```

Rx is available for many languages, you'll find a video with an introduction of RxJS for Javascript here, http://youtu.be/FqBq4uoiG0M

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you're looking for is an [*interceptor*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interceptor_pattern). You can have your `PriceFeed` pass its list of observers to a new `PriceFeedInterceptor` that watches the `PriceFeed` and passes on either the regular or overridden price as appropriate.  Your observers shouldn't need to be changed, but the `PriceFeed` will have to know about the interceptor and be prepared to delegate to it.